# Ruby on Rails: what does "equals" symbol mean as a parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, equals

Some open source I've been using has the below line as a function declaration:

def parse_query(query=nil, options={}, models=nil)

What effect do the "equals" symbols have on the statement? Does it just make the parameters optional?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sets the default value of the parameter, if the person calling the function does not specify one.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to Python and C++, the equals sign in the parameter list lets you specify a default parameter.  For example, in Python:

```
def hello_world(message="Hello World"):
    print "message = "+message
```

Calling this function like this:

```
hello_world()
```

Will result in:

```
message = Hello World
```

But calling the function like this:

```
hello_world("changed default")
```

results in:

```
message = changed default
```